# What are examples of open data platforms for government, with support for Arabic language?

Tags: data-portal

I would like to know which platforms can be used in government for open data access and customizable and support Arabic language.

Comment: Best is not quantifiable, but there are plenty of options that you can weigh on. You should look at the question regarding differences between ckan and socrata. nucivic and dkan are also options. Essentially it comes down to what said government is/is not willing to do regarding support/setup/analytics/etc.

Comment: Actually, I would who already used these tools to share their experience, if there had any difficulties implementing one of these tools, I agree with you government is willing to outsource the development and operation services, as well migrating the data. but most of analytics part will be done by data consumers and government agencies as well

Answer (score 1):

For Europe I would point you to the [OpenDataMonitor](http://opendatamonitor.eu) project website. As pointed out "best" is not really an objective measure.

The project also has a [know-how site](http://knowhow.opendatamonitor.eu/odresearch/open-data-software-and-apis/) which may have further information.

Here is a [video](http://www.safe.com/webinar/open-data-portals-9-solutions-and-how-they-compare) that lists and compares the most common solutions.